# Suppose variance of X is finite, how to show X is square-integrable

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Suppose $Var(X)<\infty$, how to show that $E(X^2)<\infty$?

$Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2<\infty$, but what about $[E(X)]^2$? Is that also finite?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you define $\text{Var}(X)$? If you *define* $\text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X))^2$ and $\text{var}(X)<\infty$, then by assumption $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$ because otherwise $\text{var}(X)$ is not even well-defined.

Comment: @saz That's a good point. So the "variance of X is finite" already contains "the expectation of X is finite or well-defined". Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: A way to attribute a "variance" to *every* random variable $X$ is to consider $v(X)=\inf\limits_xE((X-x)^2)$. Then $v(X)$ exists for every $X$, $v(X)$ is the variance of $X$ when $E(X^2)$ is finite and $v(X)=+\infty$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) $\operatorname{Var}X:=\mathbb{E}\left(X-\mu\right)^{2}$ where $\mu$ denotes
$\mathbb{E}X$.

So expression $\text{Var}X<\infty$ only makes sense if $\mu$ is
properly defined, i.e. if $\mathbb{E}\left|X\right|<\infty$.

In that context it is somehow absurd to *prove* things like $\mathbb{E}\left|X\right|<\infty$
on base of $\operatorname{Var}X<\infty$. It must be seen as a preassumption.

The rule $\operatorname{Var}X=\mathbb{E}X^{2}-\mu^{2}$ tells us that statement
$\text{Var}X<\infty\wedge\mathbb{E}X^{2}=\infty$ cannot be true.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right. I think I just mess up with the definition.

Comment: You are welcome.