# Is the variance of a random variable finite if and only if the first two moments of the random variable are finite?

Tags: probability-theory

I don't know measure theory very well, and I'm not looking for a very detailed proof.

Suppose $X \in \mathcal{L}^2$ (I believe this means that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ exists, which implies that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ exists by something I've already proven). The variance of $X$ is defined by $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]$. It then follows that we can write the variance of $X$ as $\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right)^2$.

What I'm wondering is, is the converse true? That is, if the variance is finite, then $X \in \mathcal{L}^2$? By definition of the variance, $X \in \mathcal{L}^1$ since $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is in there. But how do we know that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ exists?

I have already read [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089459/suppose-variance-of-x-is-finite-how-to-show-x-is-square-integrable?rq=1), but I don't quite understand it, since writing the variance as $\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right)^2$ assumes that $X \in \mathcal{L}^2$ anyway.

Comment: Assume $X\in\mathcal{L}^1$ and $\mathbb{E}[((X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2)]$ is finite. Then $$ X^2 = (X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2 + 2X\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$$
and everything on the RHS is integrable by assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate $X^2\leq 2(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2+2\mathbb{E}(X)^2$.